# How to use data validation to restrict selection to a list with all unique entries in a column and one additional?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do the following: I have a table = Listobject which has a column called MasterID. Some columns have the same MasterID and some have even non. I need to manually add the missing MasterIDs.

I want take a row where the MasterID is empty and then I want to click on the column MasterID and select an ID for this column. It can either be an existing ID. Which is the unique lsit of used MasterIDs in the hole listcolumn OR it can be a new MasterID. If a new ID is selected it should be the next integer from the biggest MasterID. So if the highest masterID up until now was 1000 then the new one should be 1001.

So I wanted to know if there is a way to use data validation in order to suggest me the next bigger MasterID or all existing. Since the already filled MasterIDs are randomly distributed I need to make this into a single formula.

Lets formulize this a little:

IF the cell is NOT EMPTY it can be whatever it wants to be, ELSE the cell needs to be one of the values used in the listcolumn OR the MAXIMUM of the Listcolumn +1.

If possible I would like to use a dropdown list.

I have tried this with a data validation list option but I couldn't figure out how. I know there needs to be a structur like this:

```
If Isempty then BeWhatever
Else Be DynamicAdjustedListofEntries OR MaximumEntry+1
```

I have thought of doing this with a macro but I don't want to update this everytime I change something. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data, along with the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think dynamically filling up the list type of validation is possible using pure Excel. Here's my solution using VBA. Place this macro in the appropriate worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = Range("Table26[MasterIDs]").Column Then
        Dynamic_Data_Validation "Table26[MasterIDs]"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** Change `Table26[MasterIDs]` according to your data.

Then paste this in a normal module. You can, of course, paste these lines directly into the Worksheet_Change procedure.

```
Sub Dynamic_Data_Validation(table_range As String)
    Dim ids() As Variant 'Didn't declare as Long because JOIN function doesn't accept it

    Dim row_count As Long
    Dim src As Range, tmp_rng As Range
    Dim validation_list As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set src = Range(table_range)
    ids = src.Value

    'Change X to some other column name if you don't prefer this
    Set tmp_rng = Range("X1").Resize(UBound(ids))
    tmp_rng = ids

    'If sorted in descending order, it becomes difficult to add the
    '(MAX + 1) ID in the beginning of the array
    tmp_rng.Sort Key1:=tmp_rng, Order1:=xlAscending
    tmp_rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1

    row_count = tmp_rng.End(xlDown).Row

    'Add the (MAX + 1) ID to the end of the range and resize it
    tmp_rng.Cells(row_count + 1).Value = tmp_rng.Cells(row_count).Value + 1
    Set tmp_rng = tmp_rng.Resize(row_count + 1)

    tmp_rng.Sort Key1:=tmp_rng, Order1:=xlDescending
    ids = Application.Transpose(tmp_rng)
    tmp_rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'Perhaps consider adding a code to save the workbook after this line,
    'as pressing CTRL + END will move the cursor to column X or whatever you choose

    validation_list = Join(ids, ",")

    'The existing validation needs to be deleted, otherwise it raises error
    src.Validation.Delete
    src.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=validation_list
End Sub
```

I've used the worksheet to place the array items temporarily for sorting and removal of duplicates, because this seemed easier. An alternative is to manipulate the array elements within the array itself and then passing it as an argument to `VBA.Join`.

Here's the output:

[image: Dynamic Data Validation]